# How can I import pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, pandas-datareader

- I just downloaded Visual Studio Code, and I´m having troubles with importing the library in the newest version of the software.
- I hope someone can give me an instruction step by step.
- NOTE: I'm using python as my coding language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The following instructions are for versions of packages current as of this writing.
- [pandas-datareader documentation](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/devel/)
- The module is not part of `pandas` and must be installed separately
- Use the directions at [Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) to properly configure VS Code to work with your python interpreter.

### `pip`

- As per the documentation at [pydata / pandas-datareader](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader)

```py
pip install pandas-datareader
```

### `conda`

- Use this method if your python was installed as part of the Anaconda distribution.
- [anaconda / packages / pandas-datareader](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas-datareader)

```py
# at the anaconda prompt
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

### Usage

```py
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

### Note

- For older versions of `ipython` (e.g. 3.x, which is from before 2015-08), `!pip install pandas-datareader` may work (mentioned in a comment).